# Leave+be+(past participle) or (past participle) without be

Tags: grammar, passive-voice, construction, grammaticality

I am a bit confused with the construction. If we would like to say that we leave the object in that state (using a past participle), would we need *be* before the past participle? For instance: *I left number five (be) unanswered*

Comment: This is, in traditional grammar terms, an object (or objective) complement construction. Depending on the verb and the complement, the complement follows its object directly or might be preceded by *to be* or *as*. It's complicated. Here, you need: *I left number five unanswered.*

Comment: Thanks. Let's wait for others to respond as well